# Unable to access WatchKit app assets

Tags: xcode, swift, watchkit, watchos-2, apple-watch-complication

I need to use some images in my WatchOS app and its complications. If I put them in the assets catalog inside the watchkit app target group I can't access them from my WatchOS app, but in the extention assets catalog I can.

This is the test image: 
[image: CircularSmallRingImage42mm@2x.png]

This is how I tested the accessibility:

- I dropped a png file into watchkit app assets. XCode created an image set ad put the image in the 2x slot.
- I copied the name `CircularSmallRingImage42mm` from Attribute Inspector.
- I added the following code in the `awakeWithContext()` method in my initial `InterfaceController`:

  ```
  if let image = UIImage(named: "CircularSmallRingImage42mm") {
      NSLog("works")
  } else {
      NSLog("doesn't work")
  }
  ```
- I reset content and settings on the Apple Watch Simulator.
- I cleaned and ran the watchkit app scheme on iPhone 6s Plus + Apple Watch 42mm simulator. **Doesn't work.**
- I deleted the image set and repeated the procedure, except for this time I dropped the image in app extension's asset catalog. **Works.**

The assets catalog in my watchkit app group is targeted only on watchkit app. The assets catalog in my watchkit app extension group is targeted only on watchkit app extension. Everywhere I look people seem to recommend putting static content into an asset catalog bundled with the Watch App target so it gets stored on the watch itself.

Why can't I access the image? Am I doing something wrong? Is the watchkit app bundle not the recommended place for storing static files?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the name of the image, it sounds like it's related to a complication.

Complication images belong in the WatchKit Extension Asset Catalog, since the complication is an "extension" of your app. Your app doesn't have to be loaded or running for the complication to function.

You also need to refer to complication images by their group name if they're stored in the Complication group. E.g.,

```
UIImage(named: "Complication/Circular")
```

For more details, see [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7426) at the Apple Developer forum.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build a complication, but for testing purposes I just dropped the image in the assets, thus creating an image set. I am calling the methods from custom controllers so the testing scenario should have nothing to do with complications. I am also avoiding complication assets because of the inconsistencies with the dimension requirements mentioned in that thread. I was following the instructions of this guy: [link](http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/118580394879/watchkit-image-tips), claiming the images are transferred to the watch during installation. Is he wrong?

Comment: That blog entry was written back in watchOS 1, when the watch extension ran on the iPhone. There's no longer any image transfer, as both the app and the extension assets are already situated on the watch. As you already discovered by testing, the images belong in the extension asset catalog.

Comment: I understand now that I have to use the extension assets, but I still don't understand why the wachkit app assets are inaccessible.

Comment: Think of the app assets as static resources used at load time by the system (e.g. Storyboard resources, app icons), and the extension assets as dynamic resources used at runtime when your code directly accesses them.

Answer (score 0):

The Assets for iphone app and for watch app is totally different you can't access the images into app asset folder to watch extension. You have to add new images which compatible with the watch kit